# Getting text of a table element. [HTML, CSS, Javascript, JQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been just experiments with code and I can't seem to get this to work. I'm trying to make it so I can alert the text of the element when I click it but nothing is alerting, the link to the project is below. The code will also be put in. 
Link to project: http://jsfiddle.net/enmydky4/

Code if you don't want to go to link:

```
HTML
<body>
    <table id="Table">
        <tr id="Row1">
            <td class="hvr-outline-out">Item 1</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>Item 4</td>
            <td>Item 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Row2">
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>Item 4</td>
            <td>Item 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Row3">
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>Item 4</td>
            <td>Item 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Row4">
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>Item 4</td>
            <td>Item 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Row5">
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>Item 4</td>
            <td>Item 5</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button id="Button">test</button>
</body>

JQuery/Javascript
$('td').click(function() {
    alert("Hello");
});
```

Comment: Doesn't `$(this).text()` get you what you want?

Answer (score 0):

This is a jquery code:

```
$('td').click(function() {
      alert("Hello");
      alert($(this).text());
});
```

It will not run, if you do not include jquery library:
DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/enmydky4/7/

Comment: It still displays `Hello`, not the text of the TD that he clicks on.

Comment: @Barmar his problem was the jquery, I am sure once he could make `alert` work, he could move forward, make some trials and print the text of the cell.

Comment: I'm not so sure about that.

Comment: OP wanted to display the text of the td that was clicked on.  e.g "Item 1".

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
alert($(this).text());
```

Also, you need to **include** jquery in your 
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enmydky4/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working jsfiddle based off of yours: http://jsfiddle.net/enmydky4/13/

All you needed to do to get it to work was enable jQuery as part of the dependencies and also change alert "hello" to alert `$(this).text();` instead.

For posterity's sake here is a snippet of your code working as well:

```js
var Items = document.querySelectorAll("td");
var Random = function (Multiplyer) {
    return String(Math.round(Math.random() * Multiplyer));
};
var FuncRGB = function () {
    var RGB = [Random(255), Random(255), Random(255)].join(",");
    return RGB;
};
var SetSquares = function () {
    var RGB = FuncRGB();
    for (var i = 0; i <= Items.length; i++) {
        Items[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + RGB + ")";
    }
};

var tableAlert = function (e) {
    alert(e);
};

//document.getElementById('Table').addEventListener("click", tableAlert, false);
document.getElementById("Button").onclick = SetSquares;
$('td').click(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    alert(text);
});
```

```css
td {
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 5px;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
/* Outline Out */
 td:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    border: solid 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
td:hover:before, td:focus:before, td:active:before {
    top: -8px;
    right: -8px;
    bottom: -8px;
    left: -8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <table id="Table">
        <tr id="Row1">
            <td class="hvr-outline-out">Item 1</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>Item 4</td>
            <td>Item 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Row2">
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>Item 4</td>
            <td>Item 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Row3">
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>Item 4</td>
            <td>Item 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Row4">
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>Item 4</td>
            <td>Item 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Row5">
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>Item 4</td>
            <td>Item 5</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button id="Button">test</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution without jquery you could do the following.

Get all td elements by

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
```

Then loop over them to add your event handler

```
for ( var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
 tds[i].addEventListener('click', tableAlert, false);   
}
```

And in your tableAlert function do

```
var tableAlert = function (e) {
  alert(e.target.innerHTML);
};
```

```js
var Items = document.querySelectorAll("td");
var Random = function (Multiplyer) {
  return String(Math.round(Math.random() * Multiplyer));
};
var FuncRGB = function () {
  var RGB = [Random(255), Random(255), Random(255)].join(",");
  return RGB;
};
var SetSquares = function () {
  var RGB = FuncRGB();
  for (var i = 0; i <= Items.length; i++) {
    Items[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + RGB + ")";
  }
};

var tableAlert = function (e) {
  alert(e.target.innerHTML);
};

var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for ( var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
  tds[i].addEventListener('click', tableAlert, false);   
}

document.getElementById("Button").onclick = SetSquares;
```

```css
td {
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 5px;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
/* Outline Out */
 td:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    border: solid 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
td:hover:before, td:focus:before, td:active:before {
    top: -8px;
    right: -8px;
    bottom: -8px;
    left: -8px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <table id="Table">
        <tr id="Row1">
            <td class="hvr-outline-out">Item 1</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>Item 4</td>
            <td>Item 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Row2">
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>Item 4</td>
            <td>Item 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Row3">
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>Item 4</td>
            <td>Item 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Row4">
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>Item 4</td>
            <td>Item 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Row5">
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td>Item 4</td>
            <td>Item 5</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button id="Button">test</button>
</body>
```